# How to filter Mapbox Markerclusters?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Since layers are projections of the source, and clusters are basically layers too, filtering the layers have no effect on the clustering, and the filtered out objects will still be visible on the cluster layers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly it gave me a lot of trouble to figure out, and I came to a kind of hacky solution, but it works, and gives your application a lot better performance than manually filtering your GeoJSON features.

The Mapbox devs gave us the possibility to filter sources, but you cannot call `.setFilters()` on it later, there is basically no proper way to dynamically update it, which would be completely necessary to make a marker filtration function work.

If you use a dynamic filter, updating it will have no effect on your source, however, once you update the source content itself, it will update the filter as well.

So you want to initialize your source with a similar filter:

`filter: ['match', ['get', 'layerType'], this.filteredLayers, true, false],`

With this filter your GeoJSON features need a `layerType` field in `properties`, and if the `filteredLayers` array has it, it will be displayed.

You have to separately store your source data to be able to update it again the following way (or you can wait for the next iteration if you are using real time data for example).

```
    this.filteredLayers.push('restaurants');
    this.map.getSource('places').setData(data);
```

With this method you don't need a layer filtration logic, you only write filters like this to the source itself, and the clusters will properly display the visible data only too.

Another important thing is here that once you create a new array instance, the whole thing breaks. You must use `.push()` and `.pop()` only to filter the data.
You can write a filter removal function by sorting the filters first, and then popping them out one by one.

I've seen many people struggling with this issue and couldn't find this solution online, so I thought I would share.